# Humming and voltage drop on p channel Mosfet

Tags: mosfet, pwm, high-side

I am designing a high side switch using P-Mosfet to drive a heat element.
The Mosfet is driven by PWM from MCU, which in the test is around 40Hz, 10% duty.

Here is the schematic I am testing. I am driving the AOD403 with a N-channle mosfet. The heat element is supplied with 24V.
[image]

I am facing 2 issues here, one is that there is a unexpected amount of voltage drop between Source and Drain of the P mosfet, when the Mosfet is turned on. From the scope shot, we can see the voltage drop is around 3V. Where is the voltage drop coming from? The Rdson of the is pretty small, around 7mOhm or less. The current is maximal 6A, should the voltage drop just be maximal 28mV, right?

Yellow is the PWM from MCU;
Blue is the voltage across the heat element;
purple is scoped at the Gate of AOD403.
[image: Yellow is the PWM from MCU, Blue is the voltage across the heat element, purple is scoped at the Gate of AOD403]

The other issue I am facing is that when switching the heating element using PWM, the circuit is runing with audio humming. Is there some way to over coming this?
Here is the scope shot with the rising edge.
[image]

Any hint is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Your circuit looks OK for 40Hz operation.  Maybe you have a damaged FET?  Have you tried replacing it? The maximum Vgs for this part is 25V, so you might want to check your supply tolerance to be sure you can't exceed it.   40Hz is low enough that dimensional shift is causing your audio noise problem.  You could eliminate it by increasing the PWM frequency.  You might not have to go up to 20KHz, but if you did you would guarantee that you wouldn't have noise.  You would have to re-design the gate drive to operate at that frequency.

Comment: How did you measure the voltage drop? I only see the voltage across R4 in your scope traces, not across M1. Scopes are not very accurate for voltage measurements, and your supply voltage might be sagging.

Comment: Hi John D, thanks for your reply. Indeed, I didn't considered that the FET might be broken. About the audio noise, I did tried 400Hz at the beginning, The Audio noise is actually more hearable. And what is the dimension shift you are talkiing about here?

Comment: Hi marcelm, indeed, I might need to check my voltage of power supply. Or really measure the Vds over the FET to confirm the voltage drop. Thanks.

Comment: You should _definitely_ measure Vds directly, that's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @marcelm is correct, you should measure the Vds directly, or at least make sure your supply isn't sagging.  The dimensional shift is the physical change in size or position of your components that's causing the audio noise (Thermal and/or magnetostriction/magnetic).  You could increase the PWM frequency to 20KHz, but you'd need a fast gate driver to avoid excessive losses in the FET.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I would do the measurement one more time. I have a further question: how can I increase the rise time of the purple signal (the gate of AOD403), so that the falling time of the heat element would be more sharper. Will decrease the value of R1 help?

Comment: "Will decrease the value of R1 help?" - yes.

Comment: Try checking your connection from the power supply and to your load.  At 6 amps, the leads and connections only need to have 0.5 ohms to give you the drop you are seeing.  Add some heavy gauge wire and see if it improves.

Comment: Not an answer to your original question, but is there any reason for not having your heating element high side and just use a normal NFET tied to ground?